# When is a Home not a Home (Launcher related)

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am running into a very strange situation whereby I am getting a list of all the installed packages that have a CATEGORY_HOME intent.

My intention is to manually launch the native Home application (which is currently NOT the Default native Home application, because my application has that role).

So, the method I'm using (beneath) correctly identifies that there are two apps that are set up as CATEGORY_HOME.

When I try to launch the one that is mine (fetching the Launcher activity) it works fine. However, when I try to fetch the Launcher activity for the default one, it comes back as null.

So... I'm stumped.  How do I determine what I should actually be launching when  the package name of the stock home app returns null when I try and pull the relevant Launch activity via  `getLaunchIntentForPackag` from it?

Here's what I'm doing (with some comments to avoid confusion), and for the record I know that not all of them will have the expression "android" in the name space, but I'm trying to get this to work initially on a device that does come back with that string so that part of it isn't the issue.

```
            //get a list of all apps that set themselves up as CATEGORY_HOME
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = ((PackageManager)getPackageManager()).queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    String packageName = null;
            //look for the one that has the word android in the package name
    for(ResolveInfo ri : list){

        if(ri.activityInfo.packageName.indexOf("android") != -1)
            //this does get set correctly and looks like "com.sec.android.app.launcher"
            packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
    }

    PackageManager pm = SlidePlayer.this
            .getPackageManager();
    Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

    //it is NULL so this doesn't work
            startActivity(it);
```

***EDIT

Trying out the following methodology based on CommonsWare's advice...

```
String packageName = null;
    String className = null;
    for(ResolveInfo ri : list){
        //L.d("HOME PACK = " + ri.);
        if(ri.activityInfo.packageName.indexOf("android") != -1){
            className = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.className;
            packageName = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        }
    }

    //PackageManager pm = SlidePlayer.this
            //.getPackageManager();
    Intent it = new Intent();//pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            //both packageName and className appear to be set correctly
             //packageName = "com.sec.android.app.launcher"
            //className = "com.android.launcher2.LauncherApplication"
    it.setClassName(packageName, className);
    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(it);
```

***EDIT 2****
semi huzzah...

On one device (Samsung Note II) the key is to set it via Component like so...

```
     Intent it = new Intent();//pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
it.setComponent(cn);
//it.setClassName(packageName, className);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(it);
```

This doesn't work on the Samsung Tab 10" or the Motorola M (which are the only other 2 devices I have thus far tested with this methodology).

Answer (score 2):

`getLaucnIntentForPackage` looks specifically for `CATEGORY_INFO` or `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` - not `CATEGORY_HOME`, in which case it will return *null*. From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29):

> public abstract Intent getLaunchIntentForPackage (String packageName)
>
> Added in API level 3 Return a "good" intent to launch a front-door
>   activity in a package, for use for example to implement an "open"
>   button when browsing through packages. The current implementation will
>   look first for a main activity in the category CATEGORY_INFO, next for
>   a main activity in the category CATEGORY_LAUNCHER, or return null if
>   neither are found.

Comment: yep... I believe I'm using it correctly. The CATEGORY_HOME flag is used to pull all the packages that have that flag (currently finding 2... my own and the native one).  Then I use the getLaunchIntentForPackage to look for the relevant CATEGORY_LAUNCHER Activity from that package.  Are you saying that the default Launcher has no CATEGORY_LAUNCHER activity?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. You should be able to check the intent filters by adding the GET_INTENT_FILTERS flag to your package info request.

Comment: what am I checking the intent filters for? And then when I have what I need, what do I actually call to launch the app?

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I try to fetch the Launcher activity for the default one, it comes back as null.

That's because most firmware home screens are not designed to be launched by home screens, and so probably do not include a launcher activity.

> How do I determine what I should actually be launching when the package name of the stock home app returns null when I try and pull the relevant Launch activity via getLaunchIntentForPackag from it?

Since it is a home screen, you know that it must have an activity with the same `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` as you do. Find that one and start it.

Comment: Hi Commons. As always, thanks very much for your help.  Could you please elaborate on that last sentence? It is precisely the "how do I locate that activity" that I'm currently stumped on. I'm not clear on what you mean.  When you say "same ACTION_MAIN / CATEGORY_HOME" what are you referring to? same as what? and how do I fetch them?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: With regards to my last sentence, you already *found* the activity you need to launch, in the code you have listed. The `ResolveInfo` contains the name of the activity that you want, by means of the `activityInfo` object.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but when I try to do what you will find in my Edit (above) nothing happens at all (no Exception, no effect... nothing).

Comment: figured it out... the key is to launch it via ComponentName

Comment: umm... ok, I take that back, it works on one device but gives me this error on another: "version error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.motorola.homescreen/com.motorola.homescreen.LauncherApplication}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: First, your `Intent` does not have `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`. Take the exact same `Intent` you are using with `queryIntentActivities()`, call `setComponent()` on it, and use that. After all, that should be the same thing that your own home screen is doing its your own launcher (except in that case using `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` instead of `CATEGORY_HOME`).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: That being said, your Motorola error is rather strange. The activity must exist, otherwise you should not be getting it via `queryIntentActivities()`. The only scenario that I can think of that might explain it is that it is not exported, yet somehow is able to be started by the firmware itself during the normal boot process (when it is the home screen, of course). If that is the case, you're probably out of luck in terms of starting it yourself.

Comment: the odd thing is that it only works on one device out of about 6 that I've tried. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what it might be.  However, all the devices other than the Note2 are giving me the same error I posted above.